# Как получить текст JSON со страницы в Интернете

Tags: java, json, url

Я хочу знать **самый простой способ получения JSON текста со страницы в Интернете** на языке **Java**.

Например, я хочу получить с этой страницы с JSON (https://api.brawlstars.com/v1/brawler/) строку "reason".

Comment: Привет. С приземлением на стек. На каком языке ты обращаешься к url?

Comment: На Java. Хочу получить JSON со страницы

Comment: Прости я сонный, пропустил в ТС про Java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308554/simplest-way-to-read-json-from-a-url-in-java тут на импортном языке, а вот на русском https://coderoad.ru/4308554/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%B8%D0%B7-URL-%D0%B2-java

Comment: Я эту знаю, но там я ничего подробно не понял, поэтому решил задать вопрос здесь и получить конкретный ответ без кода в 40 строк.

Comment: Без кода в 40 строк не выйдет :( Погугли GSON (либа гугля для Java JSON) простая и удобная.